# Configuring for GeoWebCache in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wms, geowebcache

I have developed a web map application by using GeoServer 2.4.0 and tomcat 7 in Windows XP.

I have tried to configure the GeoWebCache for WMS layers to speed up the service but unfortunately it didn't work for me. I did something wrong in configuration steps.

Can you help me to achieve this?

I have attached some screenshots for reference.

[image]

**I have created New Gridset for EPSG:404000**

[image]

**I have tested with XXX.XXX.X.XX:8080/geoserver/gwc/demo Link:**

[image]

**My layer setting is:**

[image]

**And My Geoserver Log is:**

at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2014-01-18 10:30:31,901 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Problem communicating with GeoServer http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms
2014-01-18 10:30:31,901 INFO [geoserver.wms] -
Request: getServiceInfo
2014-01-18 10:30:31,901 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: No such style: ODC_Raster
at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.parseStyles(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:1386)

**My Default Raster Style:**

[image]

**My Custome Raster Style:**

[image]

Comment: I think you have issues with your style. Can you preview the layer in GeoServer? Why not try creating the layer again, start from the beginning, ensure that it is visible in GeoServer first, perhaps with a default style, then try GWC. Usually when you have those tiles that look like missing images, it means that the style is busted or you have a bad geometry in a vector (clearly not that here!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the browser there are no png tiles in the GeoWebCache.

You must go to **Tile Caching** > **Tile Layers** > **Add a new cached layer** to add your layer in GWC.

Then press **seed/truncate** and you'll see a dialog where you can choose the zoom levels and the tile format (jpg/png).

Don't forget to enable the **Disk Quota**, if you want to see the current disk space used by the cached layer tiles.